# Why image upload could be failing just in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I saw [Why is Paperclip failing silently in production + development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681536/why-is-paperclip-failing-silently-in-production-development) and [Paperclip images failing to save in production rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800375/paperclip-images-failing-to-save-in-production-rails).

In development my form uploads images correctly.

In console I see log for ImageMagick commands:

```
Command :: identify -format %wx%h '/tmp/Screen Shot 2013-05-20 at 1.07.24 AM20130526-23150-hy913i.png[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/Screen Shot 2013-05-20 at 1.07.24 AM20130526-23150-hy913i.png[0]'
Command :: identify -format %m '/tmp/Screen Shot 2013-05-20 at 1.07.24 AM20130526-23150-hy913i.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/tmp/Screen Shot 2013-05-20 at 1.07.24 AM20130526-23150-hy913i.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "10
.... more lines like these
```

In production I have:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
```

And `which convert` outputs `/usr/bin/convert`

## Update

I am using EC2.

Comment: Sometimes it's a problem with the host. For instance, Heroku won't let you write to their filesystem at all. I'd recommend using Amazon's S3 in any case- it's easier, practically free, and highly reliable.

Comment: hmm, thanks, I am using EC2.

Comment: I'm still guessing it's a problem with the production server not letting you save the files there directly. I would recommend using Amazon S3 to save the files even though you're hosting on EC2; many people I know do this. See here for a good setup tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3.